# Why does Promise.allSettled return Promise<PromiseSettledResult<Awaited<T>>[]>

Tags: typescript

If `x` is of type `Promise<T>`, I would expect `Promise.allSettled([x])` to be of type `Promise<PromiseSettledResult<T>>`. Why the extra `Awaited`?

[Source](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9208239759c8c1daf4311b22e0152a0c97e98eac/src/lib/es2020.promise.d.ts#L28)

Answer (score 2):

`T` can be anything from a simple value like a number , a promise, or a recursively wrapper promise.
The [Awaited](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#awaitedtype) type is added to handle all such cases.

From the docs:

> This type is meant to model operations like await in async functions, or the .then() method on Promises - specifically, the way that they recursively unwrap Promises.

This below example would fail in older versions of typescript which did not use `Awaited`.

```
declare function MaybePromise<T>(value: T): T | Promise<T> | PromiseLike<T>;
async function doSomething(): Promise<[number, number]> {
  const result = await Promise.all([MaybePromise(100), MaybePromise(200)]);
  return result;
}}
```

Promise.all cannot return `Promise<[number,number]>` directly, even after being passed already fulfilled `number` values 100 and 200.
The above is not a problem in the newer versions.

Toggle version [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.4.4#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwFkoBPAIxAAUYcBbLAZxAB4AVAPgAoA3KCZEAFzwWASiEt4AH3hVaDZuykzqdRgBksAawVsA3ACgo9YuiRpMufMBwBlWiAwALLKgDmHMcrmMmAbVTINOQwADTwAUEgMAC6bPAA3vrw8GB49BjwcPTIEBkAvPBQAO5QWBmyqiAAdLwQHL5EZJQq8hwAjAAMHSJhjeQVrQBMXSLRIgbJcBjIMPhZORgGAL5AA) to check